# How is let* Defined in Chez Scheme/Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, let, chez-scheme

How is `let*` defined in Chez Scheme/Racket? In particular, why does this first example evaluate to 6...

```
(let* ((let +) (a (let 2 4)))
    a)
```

...when my understanding from [exercise 3.1.3](http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/further.html#./further%3ah1) is that `let*` can be expanded to nested `let` (or even nested `let*`) statements, but expanding the above example as one would expect the interpreter to do results in an error?

```
(let ((let +))
    (let (a (let 2 4))
        a))
```

Is the implementation different than in the exercise? I would expect that first example to also result in an error due to the new definition of `let`.

Comment: Because hygiene. (I'll write a longer answer later, if someone doesn't beat me to it.)

Comment: This is a well written and interesting question!

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I understand this is a bizarre example, likely with no useful application. However, I'm teaching a young student who is learning functional programming for the first time (coming from Java), and finds amusement from trying to break the language. I wasn't sure about an answer to this.

Comment: If you actually want to see the implementation of `let*` in Racket, you can look at https://github.com/plt/racket/blob/master/racket/collects/racket/private/qq-and-or.rkt#L8 It's not pretty code though, because it has to be written in low-level Racket.

Comment: @AsumuTakikawa Wow. That's head-explodey in the way that trying to read psyntax's implementation is. :-D

Comment: I think the need to deal with multiple values also makes it much more complex than the single value case. Plus the code Asumu points to defines `let-values`, `let*-values` and `letrec-values` at the same time (lines 152-154).

Comment: In order not to scare rookies: The implementation in qq-and-or.rkt is not the normal way of defining macros in Racket. qq-and-or.rkt is part of the bootstrapping process, so it needs to be written in a *very* restricted way. It is straightforward to implement `let*` using "normal" Racket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume this definition of `let*` (I'm trying to make this as simple as possible, so it's not as "industrial-strength" as Racket's that Asumu Takikawa linked to):

```
(define-syntax let*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ;; base case
    ((_ () body ...)
     (let ()
       body ...))

    ;; recursive case
    ((_ (binding next ...) body ...)
     (let (binding)
       (let* (next ...)
         body ...)))))
```

Scheme has a concept called *hygiene*, which says that any free identifiers (i.e., identifiers that are not defined within the macro) in a macro will be bound to its value as of the macro's definition. In the case of the above `let*` macro, the free identifiers are `let` and `let*`, since they're not bound elsewhere (as `binding`, `next`, and `body` are) in the macro.

That means that within that macro, `let` and `let*` will have the values that were there at the time of the macro's definition, and user code (that surround the use of the macro) will not have an effect on the values of `let` and `let*` that are used.

One way to implement this hygiene is via *renaming*. So, with renaming, the above macro could be renamed as follows:

```
(define-syntax let*
  ;; bind g1 to current let, g2 to current let*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ () g3 ...)
     (g1 ()
       g3 ...))
    ((_ (g4 g5 ...) g6 ...)
     (g1 (g4)
       (g2 (g5 ...)
         g6 ...)))))
```

Here, the `g1` through `g6` are generated temporary symbols, usually known as "gensyms" (after the Lisp function `gensym`, which creates such things). Notice that, because of the renaming, user code cannot affect the definition of `let` and `let*` within the macro, and also the macro's binding of `binding`, `next`, and `body` do not affect any user code that may use such identifiers within the body of the `let*`.

Footnote (in case your student wants a more in-depth treatment of this): For many Scheme implementations, gensyms are uninterned (they are not entered into the symbol pool, unlike ordinary symbols, which are all interned). Then, even if the user happens to correctly "guess" the identifiers generated by the renaming procedure (e.g., even if they happen to use `g1`, `g2`, etc. in the example above), they won't actually collide with the identifiers that the macro actually uses.

However, standard Scheme does not talk about uninterned symbols, and in the context of standard Scheme, all symbols are interned, and thus it's perfectly valid for a Scheme implementation to use interned symbols exclusively, even for gensyms. In such cases, it is possible to create ways to break hygiene by colliding with the renamed symbols.

Answer (score 5):

(let* ([let +] [a (let 2 4)]) a)

becomes

(LET ([let +])
  (LET ([a (let 2 4)])
    a))

where LET refers to the let "macro" at the place where let* is defined (as Chris wrote: "hygiene").

When this is evaluated, LET will bind the value of + to let.
The the value of (let 2 4) is computed, and this is 6 (due to the binding of let).
Then 6 is bound to a. Finally the body is evaluated, and since a is bound to 6, the result is 6.

Answer (score 0):

The official definition of `let*` from R7RS:

```
(define-syntax let*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((let* () body1 body2 ...)
     (begin body1 body2 ...))

    ((let* ((name1 val1) (name2 val2) ...)  body1 body2 ...)
     (let ((name1 val1))
       (let* ((name2 val2) ...)
         body1 body2 ...)))))
```

This shows the `let*` expands into nested `let` expressions.  Your error arises because Scheme hygienic macros do not confuse the `let` binding when `let*` is defined with the `let` bound in your use of `let*`.

Comment: The question is "How is let* defined in Chez Scheme/Racket?"; I provide the exact definition of `let*` and get down voted.  Nice.  That.